# Nested UITableViews with shared scroll gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to embed a `UITableView` inside the footer of another `UITableView`. The result is meant to be a table view where one section (or footer to be specific) contains two table views that the user can horizontally scroll between. The vertical scrolling of the table view should never nest, meaning that you would never be able to scroll a nested table view without also scrolling the outer table view. This is where it gets hard because the size of the nested table view needs to allow the outer scroll to still be active, while also allowing cell reusing.

#### Suggestion 1

Embed the two nested table views inside of a `UIPageViewController` or `UIScrollView`inside of the footer. I can easily create the UI that I want by using this method, the issue comes down to scrolling and performance. First of all, what content size would the nested view controllers have? If setting it to be the same as the super view, scrolling will be handled only inside of the nested table view, and the outer table view will not scroll. If I instead set the content size to be big enough to contain every cell, scrolling works as expected but reusing cells is no longer available, since all cells will be dequeued at the same time. Not good.

A possible solution to this could be to set the nested tableview's size to the super view's size and only enable it's scroll once it covers the entire screen. This would allow the user to scroll in the outer scroll view normally, and once the nested table view is fully presented, we switch to scrolling that view instead.

#### Suggestion 2

Stick to using a single table view, and find a way to allow a certain section to scroll horizontally. I do not yet know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1:** To clarify, what you're attempting doesn't need the footer of the table view to be another table view. Instead we can create a table view with subclassed `UITableViewCell`s and populate the table view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by setting properties on the inner table views. This allows you the flexibility and control of adding/ removing more table views if needed. Make sure to set the dataSource of the inner table view to something other than your outer though, otherwise it might cause problems.

If I understand what your goal correctly, one way you could do this is to make 2 table views, and make a new dynamic table view cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and putting a table view inside there. You would have to adjust the height so that each table view fits in their respective cell for this though.

From there, you just need to set the horizontalScrollingEnabled on the property you create, *innerTableView* to **true**. Hope this helped! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a collection view inside every cell of the tableView